# Find downvotes to people's answers

Tags: support, answers, downvotes

I'm not sure if someone asked this before, I searched but found nothing about this. Is it possible to find given downvotes to people's answers?

I can find all downvotes like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=downvote

This show all down votes on questions and answers, but I'm interested in finding downvotes only to people's answers.

Comment: my way to get to old answers that cost me -1 in downvotes is as follows: 1) audit my rep [as described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43005/165773) 2) pick events showing -1 and get respective post id 3) construct the answer URL: `https://stackoverflow.com/a/<post id>`

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to filter on answers in the Votes tab of your profile (I'm assuming you want to see the votes *you* cast – you can never see what other people voted for); there's only a separate tab for up- and downvotes.

Another way to find downvotes on answers is via the [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=reputation) tab (they show up as a -1 entry on that list) but you have to open most days to see them.

Comment: I want to find all answers that I given down vote. But it would be great if can filter it *maybe in future*

Comment: @Pedram https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/579215/downvoted-answers-by-user?